# Initializing instance of class in another class constructor (python)

Tags: python

I have a two different classes (A & B for example), and I'm trying to take an instance of class A as a parameter in class B. Edit: I'm trying to create the instance within the constructor of Class B so that I can use it for subsequent methods in Class B.

Basically this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, various arguments):
        self.a_arguments = arguments 

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, various arguments):
        self.b_arguments = arguments 
        self.a = A(arguments of A)
```

In this case, how can I list the "arguments of A" when trying to create the instance self.a? When I write the arguments as self.a_arguments, they can't be accessed because they are in Class A and not Class B.  When I tried just a_arguments, I get an error that the a_arguments are not defined. Yet I don't want to have to rewrite all the self.a_arguments in the Class B constructor just so I can use them to create an instance of A.

Comment: Are you trying to take the A instance as a parameter, or create one?

Comment: I'm trying to create an instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to pass some indeterminate number of arguments to something, you should use tuple unpacking.  Here is some code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.one, self.two, self.three_or_more = *args

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, arg_for_b, arg2_for_b, *a_args):
        self.ab = arg_for_b
        self.ab2 = arg2_for_b
        self.a = A(*a_args)
```

How does this work?

Class `A` takes any number of arguments via the splat (`*`) operator.  Using tuple unpacking (`*var`), the fields of the class `one`, `two`, and `three_or_more` are assigned to the first, second, and remaining elements of the input arguments.

These could be passed as `foo = A(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...inf)`, by putting `*args` in the constructor, there can be any number of args and they are not forced to be in a list or tuple.

`B` takes two arguments for itself, and the remaining arguments are splat'd into a set to pass to `A`.

In usage:

```
>>> from module import A,B
foo = B(1,2,3,4,5)
```

---

A note on design -- it is probably a bad idea to initialize another class inside one class constructor.  It would probably be easier to understand if the code looked like this:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.one, self.two, self.three = *args

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, arg_for_b, arg2_for_b, A_obj):
        self.ab = arg_for_b
        self.ab2 = arg2_for_b,
        self.a = A_obj

>>> from module import A,B
foo = B(1,2,A(3,4,5))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest providing the constructor for B an initialised object of type A, e.g.:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, objectA):
        self.b_arguments = arguments 
        self.a = objectA

objectB = B(A(<args>))
```